# Show that this process is identically Bernoulli distributed, indepednent and stationary

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, independence, stationary-processes

Let $$\operatorname{frac}(x):=x-\lfloor x\rfloor\;\;\;\text{for }x\ge0$$ and $$\theta(x):=\operatorname{frac}(2x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1)$$ denote the [Bernoulli shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation). Now define $$X(x):=\lfloor 2x\rfloor=\left.\begin{cases}0&\displaystyle\text{, if }x\in\left[0,\frac12\right)\\1&\displaystyle\text{, if }x\in\left[\frac12,1\right)\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in[0,1)$$ and $$X_n:=X\circ\theta^{n-1}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$

> How can we show that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, considered as a process on the probability space $([0,1),\mathcal (B[0,1)),\operatorname P)$, where $\operatorname P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B([0,1))$, is an independent stationary process and each $X_n$ is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $1/2$?

I guess this is really simple, but I even fail to show the claim about the distributions. Clearly, $$\operatorname P\left[X_1=0\right]=\operatorname P\left[\left[0,\frac12\right)\right]=\frac12\tag1.$$ So, at least $X_1$ has the claimed distribution.

But how can we easily prove the other claims? What's the "trick"?

**EDIT**: The stationarity is clearly trivial, if we can show the independence and distribution claim ...

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your  definition of $\ X_n\ $.  It requires $\ X_0=X\circ\theta^{-1}\ $, but since $\ \theta\ $ is not one-to-one ($\ \theta(x)=\theta\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ $ for any $\ x\in\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]\ $), so $\ \theta^{-1}\ $ is not a well defined function. Did you mean $\ X_n=X\circ\theta^{n+1}\ $?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thanks for noting, it should be $X_n:=X\circ\theta^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\ X_n(x)\ $ is the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ bit in the binary expansion of $\ x\ $ (i.e. the coefficient of $\ \frac{1}{2^n}\ $ in that expansion). What interval must $\ x\ $ belong to if $\ X_i=a_i\ $ for $\ i=0,1,\dots,n-1\ $, and $\ a_i\ $ is some arbitrary sequence of zeroes and ones?

**Response to query in comments:**
$$\ P\left[X_1=a_1, X_2=a_2, \dots, X_n=a_n\right]=\text{Lebesgue measure of }\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{2^i}, \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\ ?\ $$

Comment: Don't you mean the binary expansion of $x$?

Comment: In any case, I don't understand exactly what you're asking, but it's clear to me that $x=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{X_n(x)}{2^n}$ for all $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: In light of my previous comment, I think it should be the coefficient of $\frac1{2^n}$ or am I missing something?

Comment: $\ 0\le x<1\ $, so it must be $\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{X_{n-1}}{2^n}\ $, not $\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{X_n}{2^n}\ $

Comment: Right. Well, that was the reason why I wrote $X_n:=X\circ\theta^{n-1}$ before. Let's go back to this definition (but only for $n\in\mathbb N$). It's clearly more intuitive.

Comment: Regarding your question: $x$ must belong to $\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i(x)}{2^i},\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i(x)}{2^i}+\frac1{2^n}\right)$. But how does this help?

Comment: Presumably you're using the convention that $\ \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dots\}\ $, but then you won't have an $\ X_0\ $.  The first term of your sequence has to be $\ X_1\ $.

Comment: Why should we need an $X_0$?

Comment: You shouldn't, but your equation (1) currently reads $$
P\left[X_{\color{red}0}=0\right]=\dots
$$.

Comment: I've already changed that. What do you say to my previous comment?